# Gradle AppEngine project file changes not reflecting without restart

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, gradle, gradle-eclipse

i wanted to know how others are hanlding this issue of file changes not getting reflected in running application which users gradle or maven (in this case gradle)

i have a gradle appengine project and while the application is running if i make any changes to static resources like HTML, CSS< JS , it not getting reflected in jetty war folder in appengine.

**this is the only reason stopping me from using Gradle or Maven.**

i wanted to konw

1. is there is any standard solutions to resolve this issue ?
2. if not what better alternative we have ?
3. how actually others are using gralde in there project during development

i am using eclipse for development

Answer (score 0):

Try using the flag for the devappserver to scan and reload :

`-Dappengine.fullscan.seconds=5` (or some number of your liking)

If using gradle, as described in this issue on GitHub : https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gradle-appengine-plugin/issues/97

If launching directly from eclipse you might have to add it in the right place of the launch configuration.

Comment: ya i have added this flag in .gradle file but no luck it doesn't reload. Note: for me reflecting the static resource changes are more important than java code changes

Comment: Did you do a rebuild after?  The way the gradle plugin works is the war is expanded out to a directory in the build folder.  Try a gradle assemble and check again.

Comment: So I just tested this again, and I don't seem to be having this problem, the static changes are reflected.  What task are you running to rebuild?

Comment: i will be using appengineRun task to run the project after which no changes will be reflecting , if you can any sample app, it would be helpful to check.

Comment: Can you add your build file to the question?

Answer (score 0):

In Maven run the 'package' goal and in Gradle run the 'assemble' task, both will update the target directory, and cause devserver to reload the application.